# How to make overflow-x: hidden on android browser?

Tags: android, overflow, android-browser

I understand from several sources that android browser does not recognize overflow property. Please help me find a work-around for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequently asked questions. And still there is no any good solution for it.
You can't also use styles such as:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

All recomendations are to use any third party library, like [this](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview)